# Microsoft Flow - Block uploading Video files to a Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am an owner of a Sharepoint site and want to make sure all members of the site don't upload video files. Since SP doesn't have the ability to filter out files by Type - I want to use Microsoft Flow to do this task.
So I have created this flow which triggers on creation of new file in Documents folder of my SP site. Then it runs a Condition, which checkes the property of "File content type" - if it starts with "video/" - then it should delete the file uploaded. It looks like this:
**@startsWith(triggerOutputs()['headers']['Content-Type'], 'video/')**

But when I run this Flow, I then get this error:
 *BadRequest. The request failed. Error code: 'InvalidRequestContent'. Error Message: 'The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'details', line 1, position 455.'.'.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post more of the Flow template? Also, which version of SharePoint are you using? You state "SP doesn't have the ability to filter out files by Type" but it does via Central Admin; there's a Blocked File Types setting in Central Admin -> Security -> General Security.

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint Online as part of Office 365 subscription. You say there's a setting to block certain types of files, but I don't get where are they? in the site settings? in 365 "Security and Compliance"? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no OOTB way to configure these settings yet. Your workaround to create a flow is just what I would have suggested. Ofcourse you can also still create a workflow that does that but why old fashioned if you already made your experience with flow.

This is a known issue and I would encourage you to vote for that feature [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12498615-custom-restrictions-of-file-types-that-user-can-up#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D).

In OneDrive you can restrict certain file types from syncing using the poweshell:

```
Set-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction  -ExcludedFileExtensions "wmf;mp4;mkv"
```

For your flow I would suggest to make an extra step "get file content" and use the content type you get there for your filter instead of the one from your "triggerOutputs"